# HTML Page not completely loading

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I am very new to web Development (but not coding), so please take this with a grain of salt.

I used Django to start a project, and am using some free **Bootstrap** themes which I found online.

On my home page, I learned how to link to another page by adding URLS and basic View functions in urls.py and views.py respectively.

The link "somewhat" works, however it seems to only load the very basics of html (No special text or colours as I have designed using the Bootstrap theme).

Here is the homepage where the link is found.

[image: HomePage (Where you click the link)]

This is what the page loads when clicked upon.

[image: Not_fully_loaded_pic]

Here is what the HTML Page should look like (When I open it through the file navigator)
[image: Fully_loaded_page]

.
.
.
.

Here is my urls.py in the homepage templates folder:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^$', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
url(r'^api/data/$', get_data, name='api-data'),
url(r'^about/$', views.AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
url(r'^test_page/$', views.test_page),
url(r'^transactions/', include('transactions.urls')) ]
```

This is the views.py inside the transaction folder (where index.html is the page I attempt to load):

```
class TransactionView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'transactions_page/index.html'

def transaction_page(request):
    return render(request, 'transactions_page/index.html')
```

Finally, my urls.py inside the transaction template folder:

```
urlpatterns = [
#url(r'^$', views.TransactionView.as_view(), name='transaction_view'),
url(r'^$', views.transaction_page)]
```

.
.
.
.

Please help me understand why this is occuring. I know it is probably something to due with where the files are located or my render inside the views

I understand my terminology is attrocious, but everyone needs to start somewhere. Web Dev is a new world for me. I am used to ML Applications.

Comment: You need to add `<base href="127.0.0.1:8000" />` in your head tag

Comment: Do *transactions_page/index.html* and *home.html* extend a common template? What is the path to your css in both pages?

Comment: Can you show your html and settings file?

Answer (score 0):

Your `css` file path is not correct, you can add following `base` tag to your head section to correct this:

```
<base href="127.0.0.1:8000" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Again sorry for being new, but what is the head file?

Comment: Sorry some typing issue, it's head section

Comment: I added that line into the index.html of both the homepage and the transaction folder but stil the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve this by loading in my static files and changing the href paths to include

```
{% static ' ... ' %}
```

then also by adding the static files directory inside settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
'/headless/Documents/IoTA/PyOTA/Bootstrap_Project/IoTA']
```

Thanks for the help